# Consistency strength of a negation

Tags: logic

Does the following situation occur?

$T$ is strong enough to interpret PA. There is a sentence $\sigma$ such that $Con(T+\sigma)$ is equivalent to $Con(T+\neg \sigma)$ over $T$, and $Con(T)$ does not imply $Con(T+\sigma)$.

Heuristically, making a decision about  $\sigma$ either way requires a jump in strength.

Follow-up question.  Can we have $T$ and $\sigma$ such that $Con(T) < Con(T+\neg \sigma) < Con(T+\sigma)$?  (The less-than means that the right side implies the left but not vice versa.)

Comment: If each one of $T + \sigma$, $T + \neg \sigma$ has higher consistency strength than $T$, then neither one of $Con(T + \sigma)$ and $Con(T + \neg \sigma)$ can imply the other. The reason is same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as $T$ is reasonable, $T$ will prove $$Con(T)\implies\forall\sigma [Con(T+\sigma)\vee Con(T+\neg\sigma)].$$ So if $T$ proves $Con(T+\sigma)\iff Con(T+\neg\sigma)$, then $T$ proves $Con(T)\implies Con(T+\sigma)$ and $Con(T)\implies Con(T+\neg\sigma)$. So the answer is no, that can't happen.

Comment: Thanks. It was a dumb question.